# How to check the Data gap in the query

Tags: sql, date, count

Scenario: in the below scenario inserted date is missing for 4/21/2021
for the latest record should check whether it has 4/20 if not then count as 1
the data starting from 4/14 to 4/20 we dont find any gap - Please help on this query

[image: please refer the image]

Let me know if more info need assume table name is TABA

Answer (score 0):

One typical way you would handle this would be to use a calendar table, containing all dates which your data might cover.  In lieu of a calendar table, we can inline one like this:

```sql
SELECT d.Date
FROM
(
    SELECT '2021-04-14' AS Date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-15' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-16' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-17' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-18' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-19' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-20' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-21' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2021-04-22'
) d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.InsertedDate = d.Date
WHERE
    t.InsertedDate IS NULL;
```

Comment: without providing the date value explicitly do we have any other option

Comment: Yes, create a calendar table in your database and keep it around for queries such as this one.  Then, you don't need to big ugly inline union all query...that would just be replaced by a reference to the calendar table.  You never told us your version of SQL, but just about every version supports making calendar tables without too much trouble.

Comment: SELECT d.AWS
FROM
(
    SELECT inserteddate = DATE_SUB(inserteddate , INTERVAL 4 DAY) AS AWS UNION ALL
    SELECT inserteddate = DATE_SUB(inserteddate , INTERVAL 3 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT inserteddate = DATE_SUB(inserteddate , INTERVAL 2 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT inserteddate = DATE_SUB(inserteddate , INTERVAL 1 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT inserteddate 
) d
LEFT JOIN sample T
    ON t.inserteddate = d.aws
WHERE
    t.inserteddate IS NULL    - getting unrecognized name in the line 4:14 (inserteddate)